# How do I pass a method as the parameter of another method using linq expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression, func

I want to create a method that runs another method in a background thread. Something like this:

```
void Method1(string param)
{
    // Some Code
}

void Method2(string param)
{
    // Some Code
}

void RunInThread(AMethod m)
{
   //Run the method in a background thread
}
```

Comment: You should pass an Action: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If your method has return value use [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) delegate otherwise you can use [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate. e.g:

```
void Method1(string param)
{
    // Some Code
}

void Method2(string param)
{
   // Some Code
}

void RunInThread(Action<string> m)
{
   //Run the method in a background thread
}
```

Then you can call `RunInThread` this way:

```
RunInThread(Method1);
RunInThread(Method2);
```

Comment: You could add 2 ways to run it in a separate thread: `m.BeginInvoke("Hello", null, null);` and `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m("Hello"));`

Answer (score 2):

I like `Task.Run` When I just want a little bit of code to run in the background thread. It even looks like it has nearly the same signature as what you're trying to define. Lots of other overloads too.

```
Task.Run(()=>{ 
      //background method code 
   }, TResult);
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx)